# Unity3D Centre Camera View to a Programmatically generated Array of Cubes depending on their Size and Height

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to learn about Sorting Algorithms by creating a Simple Sorting Visualizer. It kind of works but with large array sizes the Scene is out of view. I want to make the Camera centre the scene or even centre the Cube Game Object to the Camera by resizing it if its possible.

**Start Page**
[image: Start Page]
**Default Output**
[image: Output!]
**Output Wanted**
[image: Output Wanted]
**Menu**
[image: Menu]

I also want to show a Message when the array has been sorted and I tried using Display Dialog but for certain condition it activates twice for some reason and for some it activates when it should not have been activated. I don't have much experience in Unity. Thank you for taking a look.
[image: Display Dialog Error!]

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of different approaches you could take here.

Firstly, you could start using the camera's [Frustum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FrustumSizeAtDistance.html) to determine if all your columns fit into the camera view. If not, you can keep moving the camera back (or widen the able of view) until you fit all of the columns into your camera view.

Alternatively, you could use Cinemachine. I know.. Whhhaaa?!?! But yeah, Cinemachine has a [Framing Transposer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.6/api/Cinemachine.CinemachineFramingTransposer.html) that you could add all of your columns to, to make sure that your camera has all targeted objects on screen at once.

Judging by the content here, it looks like you're trying to set this up as some sort of presentation. You'll get a lot of "oohs" and "ahhs" if you go the Cinemachine route. Plus, there's no maths involved on your end.